# What is a formal synonym for "active involvement", in something?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

> Thank you for your *active involvement* in the project.

In the above sentence, what is a single word synonym that can be used instead of 'active involvement' in a very formal letter.

Is "thank you for being *attentive*" is a correct way of saying that?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider *engagement*, but *active involvement* seems better to me.

The suggestion of *attentive* doesn't capture the meaning. That could refer simply to someone listening carefully.